# the image remains the same after being updated and uploaded with new images

Tags: php, jquery, crud, croppie

I have uploaded the image and crop it with croppie, the image successfully updates the database and successfully enters the directory.

but the new image overwrites the old image with the same name, it was intentionally done. but the image displayed again by php remains the old image (the image has been overwritten with the new one)

Initially there was no problem but when I didn't open the project for more than 2 week there was a problem like the one above

**HTML tag**

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <h4>Profile Picture</h4>
    <hr>
     <form action="" id="form" method="post">
       <label class="cabinet center-block">
         <figure><img src="" class="gambar img-responsive img-thumbnail" id="item-img-output" />
         <figcaption><i class="fa fa-camera"></i></figcaption>
         </figure>
         <input type="file" class="item-img file center-block" name="file_photo"/>
        </label>
      </form>
</div>
```

**JS with CROPPIE**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        // Start upload preview image
        $(".gambar").attr("src", "../profile/pictures/img/<?=$profile['profile']?>");
        var $uploadCrop,
        tempFilename,
        rawImg,
        imageId;
        function readFile(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('.upload-demo').addClass('ready');
                    $('#cropImagePop').modal('show');
                    rawImg = e.target.result;
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
            else {
                swal("Desculpe, seu navegador não suporta o FileReader API.");
            }
        }

        $uploadCrop = $('#upload-demo').croppie({
            viewport: {
                width: 230,
                height: 230,
            },
            enforceBoundary: false,
            enableExif: true
        });
        $('#cropImagePop').on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
            // alert('Shown pop');
            $uploadCrop.croppie('bind', {
                url: rawImg
            }).then(function(){
                console.log('jQuery bind complete');
            });
        });

        $('.item-img').on('change', function () { imageId = $(this).data('id'); tempFilename = $(this).val();
            $('#cancelCropBtn').data('id', imageId); readFile(this); });
        $('#cropImageBtn').on('click', function (ev) {
            $uploadCrop.croppie('result', {
                type: 'base64',
                format: 'jpeg',
                size: {width: 270, height: 270}
            }).then(function (resp) {
                $('#item-img-output').attr('src', resp);
            //$('#cropImagePop').modal('hide');
                $.ajax({
                    url: "../lib/proses/upload.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {"image":resp},
                    success: function (data) {
                        html = '<img src="' + resp + '" />';
                        $("#upload-image-i").html(html);
                        $('#cropImagePop').modal('hide');
                        swal.fire(
                            'Berhasil !',
                            'Profile berhasil diubah',
                            'success'
                        )
                    }
                });
            $('#cropImagePop').modal('hide');
            });
        });
        // End upload preview image  

    </script>
```

**Upload Process**

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    require "../koneksi.php";

    $username = $_SESSION['username'];

    $croped_image = $_POST['image'];
    list($type, $croped_image) = explode(';', $croped_image);
    list(, $croped_image)      = explode(',', $croped_image);
    $croped_image = base64_decode($croped_image);
    $image_name = $username.'.png';

    // insert name to database
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET profile = '$image_name' WHERE username = '$username'";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    // upload cropped image to server 
    file_put_contents('../../profile/pictures/img/'.$image_name, $croped_image);
?>
```

> I want the newly uploaded image to appear to replace the old image in
>   the file that displays the image (ex. index file, etc.)

Comment: sounds like the image is being stored in a cache somewhere, either on the client or a service like cloudflare.

Comment: Have you checked your browser cache? Maybe try adding a random param to image path, like myimage.jpg?c=[randomNumber], this will force the browser to download the image again.

Comment: [@GuilhermeAssemany](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4602330/guilherme-assemany) 
thank you for your answer, it worked and really helped me

Comment: You’re welcome @halimlab ! I have posted it as answer. Can you accept it ?

Comment: @GuilhermeAssemany yes I will accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked your browser cache? Maybe try adding a random param to image path, like myimage.jpg?c=[randomNumber], this will force the browser to download the image again.

Answer (score 0):

Clear your cache, are you using a PHP framework?

Comment: how to clean cache use php or javaScript ?

Answer (score 0):

your image tag is being refreshed that sets old image source again. so try to stop refreshing tag. for example I was using wire:poll I simply used wire:ignore.self in image tag to avoid livewire polling. this is only if you are using livewire.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).